# SQL - How do I populate a database with the values provided in a text file?

Tags: mysql

I have a text file given as a part of the assignment and I have to use it to populate the database. I don't understand how I am supposed to use it to populate the database.

Here is an example of the text file - 
STUDENT TABLE DATA:

The row names are in this order

```
Student ID, Student name, Programme, Level, Age
10, Lorry Ross,CS,1,18
102,Lydia Ken,CIS,1,18
103,Bob Chung,CS,1,18
```

Answer (score 1):

See documentation for [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)